# MapboxMapMatching with more than 100 points

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I need to draw my custom Route from a list of points using **MapBox** api. By default , **MapboxMapMatching** accept only 100 points but my list has more than 100 points. 
Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey thanks for checking out Mapbox  The Map Matching API is able to handle more than 100 points, but you need to upgrade your Mapbox account / plan.  Follow [this link](https://www.mapbox.com/contact/sales/?page=/pricing) to contact our team if you have questions about this.  Thanks!